# Ajax throwing error after calling controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having some issues calling a controller method from my jquery ajax. The controller method is called and the data `servername` is passed in correctly. But, before my controller can return anything to the jquery, the jquery enters the error state.

Here is my jquery and controller code snippets:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("serverLookup", "QC")',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: { 'serverName': servername },
    success: function (result) {
         alert(result);
         debugger;
    },
    error: function (result) {
         debugger;
    }
});

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult serverLookup(string serverName)
{
    string data = myMethod.getData();
    return Content(data);
}
```

On top of everything. The result value given when the error is reached is not helpful at all either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send your response back as JsonResult

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult serverLookup(string serverName)
{
    string data = myMethod.getData();
    return Json(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Return a `Json`:

```
return Json(new { result: data });
```

When you make an AJAX request to the controller, it needs a `JsonResult`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that Your Content() return html. In that case You have to change dataType to html, Or change it according  to your response.